# Algebra with congruence classes.

Tags: abstract-algebra, congruences

Consider $x^2=[2]_7$ where $[2]_7$ is the congruence class of $a$ modulo $m$, or
$$[2]_7=\{x\in\mathbb{Z} \ | x\equiv 2 \ (\text{mod} \ 7)\}.$$
It is immediately obvious, by inspection, that $x=[3]_7$ and $x=[4]_7$, but is there any way to analytically attain these solutions?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "analytically"?

Comment: Just a way to derive these solutions by manipulating the equation. I think I may be missing something obvious.

Comment: How would you solve $x^2=4$ analytically? Sure, you can write $x=\pm\sqrt4$, but that's just notation, when the answer you want is $x=\pm2$ – so, how would you get that "analytically"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just compute the squares in $\mathbf Z/7\mathbf Z=\bigl\{0,\pm 1,\pm 2,\pm3\bigr\}$:
$$0^2=0,\quad (\pm1)^2=1,\quad (\pm2)^2=-3,\quad (\pm3)^2=2,$$
hence the solutions are $3$ and $-3\equiv 4\mod7$.

Comment: Very simple, thank you.

Comment: Isn't this inspection, which the OP wanted to avoid?

Comment: The only difference is I consider using $\pm$ to divide the number of items to be inspected by (almost) $2$. There's no sensible other way in a finite prime field.

Comment: For large primes, there are much more sensible ways. See, e.g., http://stanford.edu/~jbooher/expos/sqr_qnr.pdf

Comment: Of course, I only gave an elementary way…

Comment: New location of the sqr_snr.pdf file https://www.math.arizona.edu/~jeremybooher/expos/sqr_qnr.pdf

Comment: Also, for even extension
fields https://eprint.iacr.org/2012/685.pdf

Answer (score 0):

$
x^2 \equiv 2
\iff
4x^2 \equiv 8
\iff
(2x)^2 \equiv 1
$

$\iff$
$7$ divides $(2x)^2 - 1 = (2x-1)(2x+1)$
$\iff$
$7$ divides $2x-1$ or $7$ divides $2x+1$

$
\iff
2x \equiv \pm 1
\iff
8x \equiv \pm 4
\iff
x \equiv \pm 4
$

In this case we are lucky that the inverse of $2$ is clearly a square.

In other cases, we might not be so lucky: if we replace $7$ by $23$, then the inverse of $2$ is $12$, not clearly the square of $14$.